# string.Replace(@"\\",@"\") doesn't work

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have string getting from config. it's "DONGHOANG\HOANG"
I try replace `\\` with `\` but it doesn't work?
Here is my code? Have any solution

```
string linked_sv_name =
    "[" + config.AppSettings.Settings[cbbkho.SelectedValue.ToString()].Value + "]";
linked_sv_name = linked_sv_name.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

Comment: I have other question: why appsetting value is "DONGHOANG\HOANG" but when i get it, it become "DONGHOANG\\HOANG"

Comment: Where do you see it with `\\ ` ? Debugger shows that because that's an escape sequence. If you print it to console, it will be with single `\ `. Maybe that's why replace is not working either.

Comment: I see it on debugger and when i send it to sqlcomand it not work

Comment: Then post your sqlcomand and the exception

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I think problem is it. But not. I will check sqlcommand

Comment: By what you describe, your statement `linked_sv_name = linked_sv_name.Replace(@"\\", @"\");` will not have any impact on the read value due to it doesn't have a `\\` in it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing 2 slashes into 1, you should replacing 1 slash into 2:

```
string linked_sv_name = "[" + config.AppSettings.Settings[cbbkho.SelectedValue.ToString()].Value + "]";
linked_sv_name = linked_sv_name.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
```

When passing this into sqlCommand, the double slashes will become 1 slash.